# How can I get updated table data in views in SQL Server on a daily basis?

Tags: sql-server, database

I have created 7 tables in SQL Server  database, and this tables will be historical tables, that means data will be loaded daily without replacing the old data.

I have created a view by joining these tables. And my requirement here is, when ever the data is loaded in tables, the new data (current day data) should be loaded into the views replacing the old data, and it should be done when ever the table data is loaded.

Can any one please provide me an SQL query for this job?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? mysql <> sql server. Seems like in either case you would create your view with a where predicate to return only the date range you are looking for.

Comment: Do you really need 2 different tables here? Can't you just use a Date column (or any other) to know which data is "new" and which is "old", and the view just retrieves the "new" ones? Also you can't update a view (materialized views as exceptions), you can update it's underlying table's content.

Comment: I am using SQL Server Management Studio @ Sean Lange

Comment: A **view** in SQL Server is **always** up to date, since it doesn't really store any data at all - it just stores the SQL query to be executed. So if you select from your view, behind the scenes, SQL Server converts this to a SELECT against the tables that make up the view - and any new data will always, automagically, be shown, without any need for a "update query" or job .... so I guess what you really need to do is just making sure you select the correct date range of data from your view

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is create a default column on the table (named insertionDate, for example), which default value is current date, which will be the insertion date.
I recommend this approach beacause the default column prevents schema erros.
Then create a view using this column as filter via `getdate()` such as `... where insertionDate = getdate()`

Comment: But there are 7 tables in my database, from which I created a view picking columns from all those seven tables. So, I have no way of creating a Date column in all the tables and selecting it in a single view.

Comment: each table will have it's own "insertionDate"!